# set/clear interval issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

HI,

i am using the following code to show a link which is inside the li element. the constrain is, once the mouse enter into li element, and if it's stay inside 3sec, then it need to show. once i leave from li element, immateriality it should hide. for this, i am using :

```
var showTimeOut;
var thisElement

$('.user-list li').live('mouseover',function(){

    thisElement = $(this).children('a.copier-link');

    showTimeOut = setInterval(function(){
        thisElement.css({'display':'block'});
    },3000);
})

$('.user-list li').live('mouseleave',function(){
    clearInterval(showTimeOut);
    thisElement.hide();
})
```

It's work fine. But the problem is, while i cross the li element with just a second, even the interval is calling, and showing the link. but i need to show only, if i stay inside 3sec and it need to hide there after, again i stay back 3sec.

anything wrong with my code?, else any one give me the best suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you retag this to show what language your using?

Comment: I've made assumptions about language/framework and altered tags accordingly. @3gwebtrain, please change the tags if they prove to be incorrect.

Comment: do you need to use setInterval here, which will repeat every 3 seconds, would setTimeout be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

This is only a guess, but it could be to do with your use of `mouseover` instead of `mouseenter`.  `mouseover` can fire multiple times if you have child elements within the `li` element, which would set the interval multiple times and overwriting the value of the `showTimeout` variable.  This means when `mouseleave` fires, only the last interval to be set would be cleared.

Try changing your `mouseover` event to `mouseenter` instead.  I would also consider changing `setInterval` to `setTimeout`, as `setInterval` will set a timer to run a function recurring every 3 seconds here, unnecessarily applying the `.css()` again.  `setTimeout` would only call the function once.

---

Another idea would be to always call `clearTimeout` before `setTimeout`, then you know that two timers can't run simultaneously:

```
clearTimeout(showTimeout);
showTimeOut = setTimeout(function(){
    thisElement.css({'display':'block'});
},3000);
```

Comment: thanks, i changed my code in to like this now..

var showTimeOut;
 var thisElement
 
 $('.user-list li').live('mouseenter',function(){
  
  thisElement = $(this).children('a.copier-link');
  
  showTimeOut = setTimeout(function(){
   thisElement.css({'display':'block'});
  },3000);
 })
 
 $('.user-list li').live('mouseleave',function(){
  clearInterval(setTimeout);
  thisElement.hide();
 })

but still the issue is there, while i pass the mouse any one of the li element the function is calling and making the link to be visible..
any help?

Comment: @3gwebtrain: in your mouseleave handler you have `clearInterval(setTimeout)`, this should be `clearTimeout(showTimer)`.  Also, try clearing the timeout before setting it as this will rule out any duplication of timers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [hoverIntent jQuery Plug-In](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) is what you're looking for?

> hoverIntent is a plug-in that attempts
>   to determine the user's intent... like
>   a crystal ball, only with mouse
>   movement! It works like (and was
>   derived from) jQuery's built-in hover.
>   However, instead of immediately
>   calling the onMouseOver function, it
>   waits until the user's mouse slows
>   down enough before making the call.

Comment: you are using jQuery, I do not see any reason for not using this plugin, since it would exactly do what you need.